# How to stop Eclipse CDT from emitting errors due to gcc specific syntax?

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, eclipse-cdt, gcc-extensions

I'm writing some code that makes use of computed goto. The syntax checker is flagging every instance of `goto *ptr` and `&&label` as syntax error. Is there anyway to stop this?

**Addition by alk:**

Example for computed gotos (gcc extension):

```
...

void * pLbl = NULL;

if (<some expression>)
  pLbl = &&lbl1;  /* gcc extension: no, '&&' is not a typo */
else if (<some other expression>)
  pLbl = &&lbl2;  /* gcc extension: no, '&&' is not a typo */

if (pLbl)
  goto * pLbl;  /* gcc extension: goes/jumps to either 'lbl1' or 'lbl2' */

goto lbl0;

lbl1:
  <do some stuff>
goto lbl0;

lbl2:
  <do some other stuff>
goto lbl0;

lbl0:

...
```

(`eclipse` seeing this code gets yellow all over)

Comment: Put some code please, I don't understand the question.

Comment: I wonder why this was voted down. Is it considered of topic here? It is good style to leave a comment if down voting, isn't it?

Comment: Example added for better understanding ... @JulienFouilhé

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way other then filing a bug to the [CDT bugtracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT), preferably with a patch for the parser.

Comment: There already is an entry referring this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=84144 Could perhaps someone clarify what the comments on this bug report want to say?

Comment: The original report was filed in...Feb 2005. The chance of this getting fixed doesn't look good. I'm just going to turn off the feature. It's giving me other spurious warnings as well. I'm having trouble doing that though. I unchecked all the checkboxes in Preference > C/C++ > Code Analysis and the darn errors are still popping up.

Comment: @cleong Have you been succesfull with turning of such feature. I am facing the same problem. Situation did not changed in CDT over time.

Comment: @Mihalko. Nope. Have to turn off syntax checking altogether.